# How to use Master/Slave doctrine2 configurations from Symfony2 Console commands

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using the Doctrine2 master/slave configuration in Symfony2 to scale my application across a single master database and several read-only (replicated) slaves.

This works perfectly from within my application and Doctrine2 sensibly uses the slave for read-only queries and the master for write operations.

If in one of my controllers, I wrote:

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
var_dump($em->getConnection()->isConnectedToMaster());
```

`isConnectedToMaster()` returns `false` - which I would expect since the slave is connected to by default.

This is also the case if I run this code inside a `WebTestCase`

However if I wrote the exact same code inside a Symfony console command (ContainerAwareCommand):

```
$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
var_dump($em->getConnection()->isConnectedToMaster());
```

`isConnectedToMaster()` returns true. Which means the master is selected as the default.

I can't find out how to stop the default connection being master from console commands. Which means if I want to run some non-critical, heavy data processing tasks from the console - they all hit the master (bad) not one of the slaves (good).

Anyone know how I can make Doctrine2 use the slave by default from the console? Or know why it always defaults to the master?

ANSWERED: Thanks to nifr who set me on the right course - I found that my problem was because I was using JMS\JobQueueBundle (which replaces the Application used by app/console with an altered one which must connect to the MasterSlaveConnection in a way which forces the "master" to be chosen). When I commented out the

```
use JMS\JobQueueBundle\Console\Application;
```

in `app/console`, the slave was correctly selected in my console test.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to make sure your command doesn't call any action that lets doctrine choose the master connection.

---

Important for the understanding of the `MasterSlaveConnection` should be how and when it picks the slave or master.

- picks Slave if Master **was never picked** before and ONLY if 'getWrappedConnection' or 'executeQuery' is used.
- Master picked when '*exec*', '*executeUpdate*', '*insert*', '*delete*', '*update*', '*createSavepoint*', '*releaseSavepoint*', '*beginTransaction*', '*rollback*', '*commit*', '*query*' or '*prepare*' is called.
- **If master was picked once** during the lifetime of the connection **it will always get picked afterwards.**
- One slave connection is randomly picked ONCE during a request.

([MasterSlaveConnection API](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.9/Doctrine/DBAL/Connections/MasterSlaveConnection.html))

Comment: My point is that even within an "empty" command - ie a command that does nothing other than get the EntityManager and ask if it's connected to the master or slave - I'm finding that it's already connected to the master.

Comment: You could debug wether one of the mentioned methods of `MasterSlaveConnection` is being called by putting breakpoints into each of them. Further you might want to put a breakpoint into the constructor to check wether the connection is actually being initialized. It could easily be that one of these methods is executed during `app/console`'s bootstrapping. If the connection is actually constructed and none of the methods is being executed there might be a configuration problem.

Comment: Do you have any tips for debugging in the app/console? I'm happy debugging (using PHPStorm) via the web interface but not in the console.

Comment: I've edited my answer - it was my use of "JMS\JobQueueBundle\Console\Application;" in the app/console which was responsible for forcing the master. When I removed it, everything worked as expected. Thanks nifr

Answer (score 3):

I ended up on this question when I was looking for a way to query either my master for writting or my slaves for reading.

Here is the magic:

- Write operations (use master): `$em->getConnection()->executeUpdate(...);`
- Read operations (use slaves): `$em->getConnection()->executeQuery(...);`

Comment: How you control SELECT FOR UPDATE?

Comment: you might be interested by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12995036/731138

Comment: Please share more details. As far as I see, `$em` does not have any property called `getConnection`. Also, the documentation above the source code tells us that the master will always be used after it got used once, so read operations won't always use the slave

Comment: Thanks, it worked! `executeUpdate` is deprecated, use `executeStatement` instead