# symfony mysql picking master connection 90% times

Tags: symfony

I have setup symfony mysql site with mysql master slave configuration. How ever while testing with jmeter I observed that almost all load is going to master and 1-2% to the server.

Referred [how to use master-slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068459/how-to-use-master-slave-doctrine2-configurations-from-symfony2-console-commands) but couldn't help. Is there any specific parameter to influence Server to pick slave connection?

**PS- I am performing all read operations only**

Comment: I have the same setup and it is working perfectly fine. Are you sure the application is able to connect to both the servers!!

Comment: yes Broncha app is able to connect to both master and slave but 95% queries go to master despite of query type(insert, update or select)

Answer (score 4):

Doctrine will use the master for all queries after any kind of update.

You can tell doctrine to switch back to a slave after inserts/updates:

```
$em->flush();
$em->getConnection()->connect('slave');
```

You could also check whether you have a request listener doing inserts/updates, and apply that fix.